# How to get a loading animation in a Makefile for the time .o files are compiling?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to get a little loading animation as long the Makefile compiles my .o files i saw a loading animation which switched between  [|], [/], [-], [] and that is what i wanna implement now.

I tried to achieve that by using printf a Make variable and some ifeq and else ifeq conditions but that didn't worked somehow the if conditions are checked just once after the first call of the
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: rule

what i expect is that the stage of the loading box switches every time the $(OBJDIR)/%.o: rule is called or somehow timebased if there is an easy solution but i think its too complicated so i would stick to the first for now

Also its my first time asking here pls be patient and tell me how to improve my questions

that is the makefile

```
# **************************************************************************** #
#                                                                              #
#                                                         :::      ::::::::    #
#    Makefile                                           :+:      :+:    :+:    #
#                                                     +:+ +:+         +:+      #
#    By: pharbst <pharbst@student.42heilbronn.de    +#+  +:+       +#+         #
#                                                 +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+            #
#    Created: 2022/05/06 09:33:42 by pharbst             #+#    #+#              #
#    Updated: 2022/11/29 03:29:26 by pharbst          ###   ########.fr        #
#                                                                              #
# **************************************************************************** #

SHELL=  /bin/bash

Black           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;30m")
FBlack          =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;30m")
Red             =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;31m")
FRed            =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;31m")
Green           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;32m")
FGreen          =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;32m")
Brown/Orange    =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;33m")
FBrown/Orange   =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;33m")
FYellow         =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;33m")
Yellow          =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;33m")
Blue            =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;34m")
FBlue           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;34m")
Purple          =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;35m")
FPurple         =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;35m")
Cyan            =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;36m")
FCyan           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;36m")
FWhite          =   $(shell echo -e "\033[1;37m")
White           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0;37m")
RESET           =   $(shell echo -e "\033[0m")
TICK            =   $(shell echo -e "\xE2\x9C\x94")

PRONAME =   libftio
NAME    =   libftio.a
CC      =   cc
CFLAGS  =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I includes -g

HEADER  =   ./includes/libftio.h
SRCDIR  =   ./src
OBJDIR  =   ./obj

FILES   =   ft_atoi.c \
            ft_bzero.c \
            ft_calloc.c \
            ft_isalnum.c \
            ft_isalpha.c \
            ft_isascii.c \
            ft_isdigit.c \
            ft_isprint.c \
            ft_memchr.c \
            ft_memcmp.c \
            ft_memcpy.c \
            ft_memmove.c \
            ft_memset.c \
            ft_strchr.c \
            ft_strlcat.c \
            ft_strlcpy.c \
            ft_strlen.c \
            ft_strncmp.c \
            ft_strnstr.c \
            ft_strrchr.c \
            ft_tolower.c \
            ft_toupper.c \
            ft_itoa.c \
            ft_putchar_fd.c \
            ft_putendl_fd.c \
            ft_putnbr_fd.c \
            ft_putstr_fd.c \
            ft_split.c \
            ft_strdup.c \
            ft_strjoin.c \
            ft_strtrim.c \
            ft_substr.c \
            ft_strmapi.c \
            ft_striteri.c \
\
            ft_lstnew.c \
            ft_lstadd_front.c \
            ft_lstsize.c \
            ft_lstlast.c \
            ft_lstadd_back.c \
            ft_lstdelone.c \
            ft_lstclear.c \
            ft_lstiter.c \
            ft_lstmap.c \
\
            ft_bufferjoin.c \
            ft_buffinit.c \
            ft_chartostr.c \
            ft_itohex.c \
            ft_ptrtohex.c \
            ft_strjoinchar.c \
            ft_strjoinfree.c \
            ft_strlower.c \
            ft_strupper.c \
            ft_uitoa.c \
            ft_printf.c \
            ft_printf_helper.c \
            get_next_line.c \
            ft_strcmp.c \
            ft_free_split.c \

OBJS    =   $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(FILES:.c=.o))

OBJ_FLAG    =   0

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):    header obj_header $(OBJS) linking_header
    @ar rcs $(NAME) $(OBJS)
    @printf "\b\b\b$(FGreen)[$(TICK)]\n$(RESET)"

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  $(SRCDIR)/*/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
ifeq ($(OBJ_FLAG), 0)
    @printf "\b\b\]"
    @OBJ_FLAG=1
else ifeq ($(OBJ_FLAG), 1)
    @printf "\b\b|]"
    @OBJ_FLAG=2
else ifeq ($(OBJ_FLAG), 2)
    @printf "\b\b/]"
    @OBJ_FLAG=3
else ifeq ($(OBJ_FLAG), 3)
    @printf "\b\b-]"
    @OBJ_FLAG=0
endif

clean: header
    @echo "$(FRed)Clean $(PRONAME)$(FGreen)             [$(TICK)]"
    @rm -rf $(OBJS)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    @echo "$(RESET)"

fclean: header
    @echo "$(FRed)FCleaning $(PRONAME)$(FGreen)         [$(TICK)]"
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    @rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all

header:
    @echo "$(FBlue)====================$(FYellow)$(PRONAME)$(FBlue)====================$(RESET)"

obj_header:
    @printf "$(FBlue)Compiling .o files         $(FYellow)[-]"

linking_header:
    @printf "\b\b\b$(FGreen)[$(TICK)]\n$(Green)Linking $(PRONAME)               $(FYellow)[-]$(RESET)"

git:    commit push

commit:
    git commit -m "$(msg)"

push:
    git push

update:
    git pull

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Answer (score 1):

peter (btw how in the world was this handle not taken prior to 2022?), first off, you really need to go to gnu.org and read the `make` manual. This is not only recommended but vital if you want to make use of the build language and concepts behind `make` and its relatives.

Secondly, and this is where I jump ahead of the chapter [How make reads a makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) which you should read first, `make` does not execute the `ifeq`'s in the way you envision: `if`, `ifeq` etc. are only used in *one* first pass when parsing the makefile to decide which parts of the makefile are parsed and which ones are ignored (forever). When `make` runs over one of its conditionals, it only parses the true-route (`if` or `else` branch) and literally throws away all lines from the false-route. This means it is of no use in creating looping constructs or repeated runtime decisions where the various branches are elicited for execution by a dynamic logic predicate. In one word, the `ifeq`'s in your example don't belong to the rule in which they seemingly are embedded but to the file as a whole.

That said, there is one more issue with your perception of `make` rules: they are executed by calling one extra shell process and therefore a completely fresh set of variables (exceptions: see the manual) **per line of a recipe** so an assignment like

```
@OBJ_FLAG=1
```

is ineffective as the process where this variable exists and has the value `1` lives only for this one line and is deleted immediately afterwards. (See `.ONESHELL` in the manual for an exemption)

The final upshot of all which I said here is that it is extremely hard to programmatically loop in `make` *in parallel with the recipe execution*. This simply never was in the focus of its development which aimed for maximum non-intrusiveness and side-stepping of the `make` process itself when some recipe process is runnnig. Adorning the build run with interactive elements is left to the user, i.e. to user-supplied programs which also would have to solve the concurrency problems of the 1:n stdout to compilation processes in a parallel `make` run. Maybe you can draw some inspirations from there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225179/display-spinner-while-waiting-for-some-process-to-finish

Comment: thx i will definitely read that manual, i used that script from unix stack... to get the makefile spinning and that works well but since i'm programming for my school and we have to write accordingly to our norm i need a way to do the same as the script but in c code. For now i'm happy with the solution and the norm problem is a problem for another day. Thx again